# Can Tutte embedding be guaranteed that each face is convex?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs, graph-drawing

In graph drawing and geometric graph theory, a **Tutte embedding** of a **simple 3-vertex-connected planar** graph is a **crossing-free straight-line embedding** with the properties that the **outer face** is a **convex polygon** and that **each interior vertex** is **at the average (or barycenter) of its neighbors' positions**.   [Tutte embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutte_embedding)

But I don’t know if this means that such embedding when first we fix **any
arbitrary outer  face (may be convex)** can guarantee that each face of is convex.

**Edit: :  Narrate more clearly, is  any internal face  convex in Tutte ebemdding?**

For example, will the following  non-convex face $f_1$ appear in Tutte embedding embedding? If it exists, is there a way to make each face convex?

[image]

References:

- Tutte, W. T. (1963), "How to draw a graph", Proceedings of the London Mathematical Society, 13: 743–767,[doi:10.1112/plms/s3-13.1.743, MR 0158387](http://doi:10.1112/plms/s3-13.1.743,%20MR%200158387).

Comment: $w$ will be placed midway along the line connecting $e$ and $z$, so the face will never appear as you have drawn it.

Comment: You might also be interested in Steinitz's theorem.

Comment: @GordonRoyle Thank you very much for your answers. I already understand what you mean, for this example, there really is no such drawing  in Tutte embemdding.  This is just an example of mine. Maybe not good. I don’t know if any non-convex face can also be excluded for the general situation.

Comment: @SamHopkins Steinitz's theorem seems to only say that there is a correspondence between a 3-connected plane graph and a convex polyhedron, but I am not sure that given an any convex(may be not) external face, it can guarantee that there is a plane straight-line drawing  where anyinternal face is all convex. Maybe I don't understand it well.

Comment: Shouldn't the Schlegel diagram of the polyhedron achieve this?

Comment: @SamHopkins haa! I personally feel you are right. 
That is to say, any 3-connected planar graph has a convex staight line drawing  which external face is anyone in face set. This is great! Of course, is  any Tttue embeddings  convex, I don’t know and very curious.

Comment: Tutte's method works with any face on the outside drawn as any convex polygon.  It doesn't matter which face you choose.  But this assumes 3-connectivity. Without 3-connectivity there might not be any Tutte drawing at all.  For a simple example, suppose there is a cut-vertex -- then some face has a vertex appearing twice so it is impossible to draw it convex.

Comment: @ Brendan McKay Thanks! For 3 connected plane graph, Besides that outside convex face, Is any inner face also convex in Tutte embedding? This is my confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that for a 3-connected planar graph, any Tutte embedding has all faces represented as convex polygons.

In the linked paper, Tutte says (page 759, before (9.3)) that a barycentric mapping is a convex representation as defined in [Convex Representations of Graphs, Proc. London Math Soc. 1960].

In this paper, he defines a convex representation to be (paraphrasing) a planar straight-line drawing that separates the plane into a finite number of regions, “each of which is either the interior or exterior of a convex polygon”.